# prove a continuity of combined function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to prove following theorem.

> Let $X = A \cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets in a topological space $X$. Let $f: A \rightarrow Y$ and $g : B \rightarrow Y$ be continuous maps. Show that if $f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x\in A \cap B$, then $f$ and $g$ combined to give a continuous function $h: X \rightarrow Y$ defined by setting $h(x) = f(x)$ if $x\in A$ and $h(x) = g(x)$ if $x\in B$.

How I can write a formal proof?

My naive proof is following

since 
\begin{align}
h(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) \quad x\in A \\
g(x) \quad x \in B \\
f(x) = g(x) \quad x \in A \cap B
\end{cases} \quad \Rightarrow \quad h^{-1}(U) = \begin{cases}
f^{-1}(U) \quad U \subset A \\
g^{-1}(U) \quad U \subset B \\
f^{-1}(U) = g^{-1}(U) \quad U \subset A \cap B
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $f^{-1}(U)$, $g^{-1}(U)$ is open, and hence $h^{-1}(U)$ is open.

I don't know why, but I feel uncomfortable about this. Is my approach fine? I think i am missing something else...

Answer (score 2):

You have to take an arbitrary open set $U$ so the special cases you considered do not prove continuity. An equivalent criterion for continuity is $h^{-1}(C)$ is closed for every closed set $C$. Verify that $h^{-1}(C) =( f^{-1} (C)) \cup (g^{-1} (C))$ to finish the proof. [Since $A$ and $B$ are closed in $X$ closed sets in $A$ and $B$ are also closed in $X$].

Answer (score 0):

From @Kabo Murphy,

Since $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets in $X$, any closed subsets in $A$ and $B$ are also closed in $X$. So to see $h$ is continuous, for every closed set $C$ in $Y$, $h^{-1}(C)$ is closed. Since

\begin{align}
h^{-1}(C) &= \{x \in X | h(x) \in C\} =
 \{ x \in A | f(x) \in C\} \cup \{ x \in B | g(x) \in C\} \\
& =(f^{-1}(C)) \cup (g^{-1}(C))
\end{align} and since $f,g$ are continuous, $h^{-1}(C)$ is closed so $h$ is continuous.